# Looping over an array of strings with an arbitrary time between each loop (JS)

Tags: javascript

I want to create an animation of strings being looped over and over again one character at a time. I have two arrays in my string:

```js
let stringArray = ['TestOne', 'TestTwo'];
```

I want to loop over said array repeatedly (string one -> string two -> back to string one -> string two -> ... continuously). I want to print the characters of string one one character at a time. After print all its characters, I will clear the printed string and proceed with the character of string two. Illustration:

```
T
Te (250 ms after the first char)
Tes (250 ms after the second char)
Test (All characters are printed 250ms after the previous char)
TestO
TestOn
TestOne
T
Te
Tes
Test
TestT
TestTw
TestTwo
... (continue with TestOne again)
```

The problem is, I want each character to be printed only 250ms after a previously printed character. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You'll be using tools like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, and unless you're using an `async` function, you won't literally use a looping construct (`for`, `while`). Instead, each callback from the timer will be the loop body.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I did use `setInterval`. I did think about using callback too, but I couldn't implement said concept (or maybe I haven't gotten it yet).

Comment: If you post your attempt, we can help you figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as long as people are posting solutions, I'll post the obvious, simple one, see comments:

```js
{ // A scoping block so the variables aren't globals
  // (unnecessary if you're using modules)
    let stringArray = ['TestOne', 'TestTwo'];
    let arrayIndex = 0;
    let stringIndex = 1;
    // Start a timer that will call the callback every 250ms (or so)
    setInterval(() => {
        // Get the relevant string
        const str = stringArray[arrayIndex];
        // Output the substring
        console.log(str.substring(0, stringIndex));
        // Move to the next character
        ++stringIndex;
        // Need to move to next string?
        if (stringIndex > str.length) {
            // Yes, go back to the beginning of the string and
            // move to the next entry in the array, wrapping
            // around if we reach the end
            stringIndex = 1;
            arrayIndex = (arrayIndex + 1) % stringArray.length;
        }
    }, 250);
}
```

This part:

```
arrayIndex = (arrayIndex + 1) % stringArray.length;
```

is a handy trick for when you have an index (0...n-1) and want to increment it and loop around. Say you have 3 entries, so the indexes are 0, 1, and 2. When you're at 2, `(2 + 1)` is `3` and `3 % 3` is `0`, so it wraps around.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the term IIFE, I've just looked it up. However, isn't trying to create less variables more favourable as we're always trying to not populate the global scope's variables?

Comment: @RichardW - It's best not to create global variables, yes, but there are **far** simpler ways. I've justed edited the above to show one of them. (I usually assume simple bits of code are in a scoping block or scoping function or module.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanations. I still think that Nina's code is pretty brilliant. Yours can achieve the same effects she did though. Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array with the `indices` and an interval for the display.

The array `indices` contaisn two values at start, `[0, 0]` which means the first item of `stringArray` and from this string the first character.

For every loopm, the caracter index gets an increment and this value is checked against the lenght of the string. If greater, then the index of the string gets an increment and the string index is resetted to zero.

To prevent the string index is greater than the actual count of strings, the value is resetted by taking a remainder assignment.

The pattern

```
(indices => () => {
    // ...
})([0, 0])
```

is an IIFE ([immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)), which takes the array as value for the first parameter. It is a closure over the array and allows to use the resturnd function as callback for the interval.

Tha advantage is to have a data set which is not changable from the outside and is avilable for any call of the callback.

```js
let stringArray = ['TestOne', 'TestTwo'];

setInterval((indices => () => {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = stringArray[indices[0]].slice(0, indices[1]);
    indices[1]++;
    if (indices[1] > stringArray[indices[0]].length) {
        indices[0]++;
        indices[1] = 0;
    }
    indices[0] %= stringArray.length;
})([0, 0]), 250)
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: I don't quite get how your code worked, but it is as I wanted. Would you mind explaining what `indices` here is? From what I see, it's a function, but what's `indices[1]++`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Sorry if I sound clueless, but what does this section mean: `(indices => () => { ... })([0, 0])`? I know that this part: `() => {...}` refers to the function, but how does the `(indices => ...)([0, 0])` becomes an array?

Comment: I see. I understand what you're doing now. Thank you for taking your time to explain what I didn't understand and for the answer. I think that your answer is brilliant. However, I've chosen Chowder's answer. Thank you again, though.

Comment: @RichardW - Nina's a **very** smart person. :-) FWIW, I'd use separate parameters rather than the `indices` array, for improved readability: `setInterval(((arrayIndex, stringIndex) => () => {
    /* ... */
})(0, 0), 250);` https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/07uv3Lgn/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you again. I got it now xD I was mostly confused due to not knowing IIFE, I'm still pretty new in JS and I'm still playing with it.

Comment: @RichardW - Yeah, and arrow function IIFEs are even more subtle. I've been writing arrow functions for years and **still** get lost in nested ones like this if I don't use line breaks and indentation to keep myself anchored.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is without using a loop, but instead using a function which takes some parameters so you know how far or long you are in a word, and which word you are currently printing in your array.

Once you are printing with a function, simply add a `setTimeout()` in the function and then you can control the delay. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp for more info on timeouts in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
strings = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= "TestOne".length; i++)
  strings.push ("TestOne".substring (0, i));
for (var i = 1; i <= "TestTwo".length; i++)
  strings.push ("TestTwo".substring (0, i));
var position = 0;
setInterval (() => {
  console.log (strings [position++]);
  if (position == strings.length) position = 0;
}, 250);
```